# How to read value from Appsettings.json for EnableQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to read the page size from configuration file. I have tried to an extend but couldn't find a solution.
This is my code.

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 3)]
public async Task<IEnumerable<users>> Getusers()
{
     try
     {
          var   users = await userServices.QueryAll();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          throw ex
     }
}
```

Comment: You can start with the fundamentals of configuration, options and dependency injection for ASP.NET Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following configuration in your Startup class:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    [...]
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config => {
        config.Filters.Add(new EnableQueryAttribute() {
            PageSize = Configuration["PageSize"] 
        });
    });
}
```

You need to add the corresponding entry to your appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "PageSize": 10
}
```

Comment: PageSize = Configuration["PageSize"]  this line complains about implicit conversion between string and an int. Any idea on how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Try with  "PageSize": "10", not sure if it will work as I didn't get the same warning...